# How to create try and else error handling for a tuple in case you have an integer

Tags: if-statement, try-catch

How to set up a try and else for when having an integer inserted instead of a tuple

```
Tuple1 = (1,2,3)
Tuple2 = (4)
Tuple3 = (Tuple1 + Tuple2)

'''
```

Comment: Do you mean `try` and `except`?

Comment: Actually wanted this - try-except-else

Comment: Actually they want me to use try-except-else-finally

Comment: Are you looking for a conditional to check whether a variable is a tuple or integer?

Comment: Yes. I know Tuple2 = (4) is not a tuple. They want me to use try-except-else-finally. Also if both are tuples ex Tuple1 (1,2) and Tuple2 (3,) than allow me to concatenate them.

Comment: Another one if one of the tuples is an integer than concating them supposed to be an empty tuple.

Comment: Should get an empty tuple instead getting an error msg. Was told If either tuple1 or tuple2 are integers instead of tuples the result of the concatenation would be an empty tuple.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this code should work

```py
Tuple1 = (1,2,3)
Tuple2 = (4,2)

try:
    Tuple3 = Tuple1 + Tuple2
except:
    Tuple3 = ()
```

Comment: Here's what they wanted - If either tuple1 or tuple2 are integers instead of tuples the result of the concatenation would be an empty tuple. Include an appropriate message in the except and else clause to let the user know if the concatenation was successful or not. Print the result of the concatenation in the finally clause.  So Under Except they want a message I think if Tuple = () than they want a message inserted in the except clause so If it's an empty tuple that must mean it's not a succesful concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tuple1 = (1,2,3)
Tuple2 = (4)

try:
    Tuple3 = Tuple1 + Tuple2
except:
    Tuple3 = ()
    print ("Concatenation failed since one of the tuples is an integer")
else:
    print("Concatenation was successful")

finally:
    print (Tuple3)
```

Comment: Finally got it now see above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.